# Forecasting of BEKK(1,1) model for 5 variables

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, volatility

I have estimated a `BEKK(1,1)` model and now I want to have forecast values of the model. Following are the `R` codes to estimate the `BEKK(1,1)` model.

```
> install.packages('MTS')
> install.packages('rmgarch')
> simulated <- simulateBEKK(2, 1000, c(1, 1))

##prepare the matrix:
> simulated <- do.call(cbind, simulated$eps)

##Estimate with default arguments:
> estimated <- BEKK(simulated)
> diagnoseBEKK(estimated)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your question (is it a question?) doesn't really make clear what you are trying to achieve (and mixes up packages / commands) I will answer to what I think you want to know.

First of all, the commands you describe come from the package **`mgarchBEKK`**, not `MTS` or `rmgarch`.

I will stick with your example, which has two series (not five, like implied by your title).

**1. Model simulation and estimation**

You run your code (example actually comes from the [documentation, page 4](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mgarchBEKK/mgarchBEKK.pdf):

```
install.packages('mgarchBEKK')
library('mgarchBEKK')
## Simulate series: (2 = number of series to be simulated,
##                   1000 = length of series to be simulated,
##                   c(1,1) = BEKK(p, q) order. 
simulated = simulateBEKK(2, 1000, c(1,1))
## Prepare the matrix:
simulated = do.call(cbind, simulated$eps)
## Estimate with default arguments:
estimated = BEKK(simulated)
```

---

Now you have all the information stored in `estimated`. Assuming your input variables would be e. g. daily return series from shares or indices the last value for H would be your forecast for the conditional variance of tomorrow and the last value for cor your forecast for the conditional correlation of tomorrow. So basically a 1-day-forecast.

---

**2. Preparing the data**

You could store the conditional standarddeviation and conditional correlation in a sepearte data frame for convienience. Like:

```
results = data.frame('bekk.csd.variable1' = estimated$sd[[1]],
                     'bekk.csd.variable2' = estimated$sd[[2]],
                     'bekk.ccor.var1_var2' = estimated$[[1]][[2]])
```

**3. Show the results**

And then show your 1-day/period-forecast for the conditional volatility and conditional correlation:

```
tail(results, n = 1)
```

Comment: @haleemasadia Glad you got it running. If the reply helped you/solved your question, please be so kind to upvote it/mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers,

I think your code is missing something. On part 2. Here is how I think it could be fixed:

```
results = data.frame('bekk.csd.variable1' = estimated$sd[[1]],
                 'bekk.csd.variable2' = estimated$sd[[2]],
                 'bekk.ccor.var1_var2' = estimated$cor[[1]][[2]])
```

Hope this helps.